# MySQL query - grouping count query

Tags: mysql

My SQL to list the total number of products by location and show only if there are more than 2 units per product.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count_product'
    FROM inventory
    GROUP BY product_no
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) >= 3
    ORDER BY product_no DESC;
```

This code gets me this output **but I also want to add another column (location) from the base table.**

```
+---------------+
| count_product |
+---------------+
|5              |
|4              |
|3              |
|2              |
+---------------+
```

**I want the output to look like this:**

```
+---------------+----------+
| count_product | location |
+---------------+----------+
|5              | Miami    |
|4              | Boston   |
|3              | Denver   |
|2              | Houston  |
+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: there will be multiple locations, what is the criteria to choose or you want to select all of them

Comment: Have you tried adding `Location` in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Is there a reason you typically don't accept answers given to your questions?

Comment: Adding Location in SELECT and GROUP BY does not return anything.

Comment: Well then, you better post some sample data for us to confirm what you're dealing with. You have the query and expected output posted but missing the data source of the expected output. Then if anyone provide you a workable answer or steer you to find a solution yourself, consider accepting their answer so that it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where the data exists. Does the city data exist on the Inventory table from which you are pulling or will you require a join? If it is on the table you already are pulling from it could look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count_product', dbo.City As 'Location'
    FROM inventory
    GROUP BY product_no, dbo.location
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) >= 3
    ORDER BY product_no DESC, dbo.location;
```

If you need to do a join, a standard join on a small query like that should work, no need for anything fancy I wouldn't think. Also you could simply say  having count(distinct location) > 2 since 3 is greater than two and so is everything else and there's no chance of it missing a 3?